# How to identify Proxy to be set in Maven's settings.xml file

Tags: proxy, maven-3

I am using home broadband. I am not sure how to get the proxy to be entered in setting.xml file for maven to connect to repos.
Normally when I open the web browser and enter any web address, I am redirected to ISP login page where I authenticate my connection and then after the I can browse the internet.

I checked my LAN settings and found nothing in there. Everything is unchecked and even Automatically detect check box is unchecked too.

How do I get to know my proxy to set the same in settings.xml for maven ?

Comment: You need to authenticate at home against a proxy?

Comment: Yes. Whenever I connect to internet, it redirects me to ISP login page where I need to key in the ID and password assigned to me. Once authenticated, I can start surfing other websites.

Comment: So you have to configure the [proxy configuration in your settings.xml file](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Proxies).